# Access violation when inserting element into global map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've been trying to debug this for hours now with no luck. I know you guys will solve the problem within minutes, so here's the situation:

I've got ~400 .cpp/.h files called ProblemX.cpp/ProblemX.h (where X is a number from 1 to 400). Each file contains the solution for a math related problem. I would like to have the problems register themselves at compile time to a global map with a unique key (just an int will work) and have the value be a pointer to the function that kicks off the math problem solution.

The global map is created and handled in files called Problem.h/Problem.cpp. However, I'm getting an "Access violation reading location 0x00000004" when the first Problem attempts to self-register in the map. The code is as follows:

In the ProblemX.h files (problem1 kicks off the solution for this problem):

```
#ifndef PROBLEM1_H
#define PROBLEM1_H

#include "Problems.h"
#include <string>

std::string problem1();
static int rc1 = registerProblem(1, problem1);

#endif
```

In the Problems.h file (problemFinder is the function that uses the global map to call the appropriate function pointer):

```
#ifndef PROBLEMS_H
#define PROBLEMS_H

#include <string>

int registerProblem(int problemNum, std::string (*problemFunc)(void));
std::string problemFinder(int problemNum);

#endif
```

In Problems.cpp:

```
#include "Problems.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<int,std::string (*)(void)> problems_map;

int registerProblem(int problemNum, string (*problemFunc)(void)) {
    int rc = 0;
    problems_map[problemNum] = problemFunc;
    return rc;
}


string problemFinder(int problemNum) {
    string retStr = "";
    retStr = problems_map[problemNum]();
    return retStr;
}
```

The access violation occurs where "problems_map[problemNum] = problemFunc;".

Thanks!

Comment: 400 math-related problems? Do I smell Project Euler?

Comment: Haha, bang on my friend. Started them a few weeks ago in an effort to relearn c++. Addictive buggers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the enigmatically named user93353 answered, the `problems_map` global is not guaranteed to be constructed before globals in other files.

To avoid the static initialization order fiasco, make `problems_map` a *local* static, that will be init'd on its first use:

```
map<int,std::string (*)(void)>&
get_problems_map()
{
  static map<int,std::string (*)(void)> problems_map;
  return problems_map;
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
get_problems_map()[problemNum] = problemFunc;
```

This ensures the map gets created as soon as it's needed, not just when the global constructors from `Problems.cpp` get run, which might be (and in your case definitely is) after the global `rc1` variable gets initialised.

Comment: Excellent answer. Solved the problem and explained why it works. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, just noticed I pasted over the `static` keyword in the `get_problems_map()` function, which is critical to it working! Corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

**Beware using statics like this.**  The order in which they are defined can make a difference.  The variable might be there but it is not necessarily constructed.  This actually bit me on the bum yesterday, so it's fresh in my memory.

In `Problems.cpp`, the order things are defined is:

```
static int rc1 = registerProblem(1, problem1);
map<int,std::string (*)(void)> problems_map;
```

That means `rc1` is initialised before `problems_map`.

Your issue therefore comes about because `registerProblem` is called to initialise `rc1` and it uses `problems_map` which has not yet been constructed.

I always thought the compiler would work this out.  But when you think about it, the general case is too difficult to consider (especially if you end up with mutual dependencies).  So I imagine the only sane thing to do is expect the programmer to put their static definitions in the correct order, just as they ought to do with any other code statements.

Comment: Hey man, I appreciate the reply, but I'm not sure I entirely understand. The "static int rc1" definition is in Problem1.h, not Problems.cpp. Are you implying that the Problems.cpp file will always be executed after the Problem1.h file? Any way to get around that?

Comment: This answer is not quite accurate, `rc1` is not initialized in `Problems.cpp`, **that's the problem**. Initialization order _within a single file_ is well-defined, but there is no guarantee of initialization order for globals in separate `.cpp` files, and `rc1` and `problems_map` are in separate files, `Problem1.cpp` and `Problems.cpp`

Comment: Oh, I had somehow ended up thinking that `Problem1.h` was `Problems.h`.  This is essentially the same problem (initialisation order), but not for the exact reasons I described.  Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Check the C++ FAQ on [Constructors](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/ctors.html). In particular check questions 10.14 to 10.18 - "static initialization order fiasco".

> What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?
>
> A subtle way to crash your program.
>
> The static initialization order fiasco is a very subtle and commonly
>   misunderstood aspect of C++. Unfortunately it's very hard to detect —
>   the errors often occur before main() begins.
>
> In short, suppose you have two static objects x and y which exist in
>   separate source files, say x.cpp and y.cpp. Suppose further that the
>   initialization for the y object (typically the y object's constructor)
>   calls some method on the x object.
>
> That's it. It's that simple.

Comment: Specifically, [10.15](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html) gives the answer